# how to secure password during ldap connection

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ldap

I have developed an mvc application where I am using ldap authendication to validate the user.

I need some help to secure my password during ldap connection. I have tried `Securesocketlayer=true` but I guess it need certificate. Its giving an error:

> handshake failure ssl.

Here is my code. I am getting a comment from my security team User credentials are sent in clear text over the network for authentication.

Can anyone help me on how to achieve this in ldap?

Here is my code:

```
using LdapConnection = Novell.Directory.Ldap.LdapConnection;
using LdapException = Novell.Directory.Ldap.LdapException;

 var ldapHost = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LDAP_HOST"];
 var ldapPort = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LDAP_PORT"];

 var connection = new LdapConnection {SecureSocketLayer = true};
 connection.Connect(ldapHost, Convert.ToInt32(ldapPort)); 

 sb = new StringBuilder();
 sb.Append(ldapLocation).Append(userName).Append(",").Append(ldapLocationIndia);
 connection.Bind(LdapConnection.Ldap_V3, sb.ToString(), password);
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Installing a certificate on your ldap server will fix this problem. Unfortunately, installing that certificate is a pain - I remember spending an hour or two trying to follow the online instructions.

Comment: I use something similar to what you are doing however I am using `PrincipalContext` and I've written my own little process to encrypt the password when capturing from the password textbox and prior to validating over LDAP.. you could write something similar and in yor ActiveDirectory routine that you write.. you can pass in the pass word in a private method where the clear text is only seen in code behind and not exposed over the network another way around it is to store or convert the password in SQL Sever using SHA it works as well

Comment: the code that I have in place is on my server at work.. however I am sure that it's not hard to write a small little program that moves bits in regards to writing a cheap little encrypt decrypt program.. `lots of examples of encryption on internet as well as SO`

Comment: im very new to .net, ok let me try something over internet

Comment: not a problem.. `Stackoverflow site` has tons of encryption examples as well as the rest of the internet.. thanks

Comment: Try looking at: http://weblogs.asp.net/jongalloway//encrypting-passwords-in-a-net-app-config-file

Comment: thanks every one. Finally i did installing certificate.